# Use screen from work table in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, blur

How can I get screen from work table and then use in my app. I want take this photo and apply blur for this photo and use it like background for my app. So I mean that I want it looks like in Siri 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to get a screenshot of the home screen on iOS devices.

You may be able to do something with a jail token device but not on a standar ios device.

Answer (score 0):

You can blur things easily, such as *your* views; but there is no official API for capturing the system's own Springboard background.